Parsing information from german vocabulary
I am a beginner programmer and I want you to look at my code and let me know if i could improve something.
First I have to enter the words in German, and then we have a loop that goes through each word and returns their HTML code to BeautifulSoup for easy manipulation.
We run several functions such as:

parse_translate()
This function will return me the translation of the word, which is clear from the name.

parse_part_of_speech()
This function will return me the part of speech, which is also clear from the name.

parse_word()
This function will return the word as it is written on the page itself.
I need this function because I can enter a word in the past form, but I need its normal form, so this function will return it to me

generate_string() at the very end, which will generate the string I need with all the information at the end.
You'll think, why do I need this function if it doesn't do much in my code?
Here's my answer: I'm going to extend this script in the future
I will probably add comparative and superlative forms for adjectives.
And for verbs, their conjugation.


And in order not to create a huge function where everything will happen, I decided to split the whole code into different functions.
At the end I used ChatGPT to make this code asynchronous, since I have never worked with asynchrony, I needed help. Before that I read a couple of articles about asynchrony in Python, but I never read any books about it
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import aiohttp
import asyncio


def generate_string(part_of_speech: str, translate: str, word: str = None) -> str:
    return f"{word} - {part_of_speech} - {translate}"


def parse_word(soup, adjective: bool = False) -> str:
    return soup.find('span', class_='vGrnd').find('b').text.rstrip() if adjective else soup.find('span', class_='vGrnd').text.rstrip()


def parse_part_of_speech(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> str:
    if soup.find(string='существительное'):
        return 'Существительное'
    if 'глагол' in soup.find('h1', class_='rClear').text:
        return 'Глагол'
    if soup.find(string='прилагательное'):
        return 'Прилагательное'

    return 'error'


def parse_translate(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> str:
    ru_translate = soup.find('dd', attrs={'lang': 'ru'})
    return ru_translate.get_text(strip=True)


async def fetch(session, url: str) -> str:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def parse(url: str) -> str:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response_text = await fetch(session, url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'html.parser')

        part_of_speech = parse_part_of_speech(soup)
        translate = parse_translate(soup)

        if part_of_speech == 'Прилагательное':
            word = parse_word(soup, True)
        else:
            word = parse_word(soup)

        return generate_string(part_of_speech, translate, word)


async def main():
    while True:
        words = input('Words: ')
        tasks = [parse(f'https://www.verbformen.ru/?w={word}') for word in words.split()]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        for result in results:
            print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


I used ChatGPT ... I’m voting to close this question because ChatGPT-generated code is not accepted.

@toolic the code was written by me, except for the asynchronicity
is it a big problem? i don't have much time to study
i was planning to start studying asynchrony in about a week since i have other things to do right now
that's why i used chatgpt for this

The point of the Code Review Community is to help you improve your coding skills, any of the code that you did not write can't be reviewed, including code generated by ChatGPT. This site also does not accept answers written by partially or totally  ChatGPT. Among other issues there are licensing issues.

annotation
These are not great identifiers.
def generate_string(part_of_speech: str, translate: str, word: str = None) -> str:

We have a verb, that's good.
But it is a vague verb, plus there's no yield so this
function is not a generator.
We do return a string, but again that is too vague.
Use vocabulary from the Business Domain.
Perhaps your Specification calls the result a "user report"
or something else which could go into the function name?
The 2nd formal parameter is a verb -- rephrase as translation, please.
Or maybe the 3rd parameter is english_word, or german_word?
So the 2nd and 3rd parameters could have parallel names that
mention which language?
The type of the 3rd parameter doesn't quite make sense.
You wanted either
... , word: str = "") -> ...

or
... , word: str | None = None) -> ...

Overall, this function doesn't appear to be pulling its own weight.
Consider deleting it, and in-lining it at the single call site
at the end of parse().
We abstract away technical details when we choose to define a function.
It gets us a little closer to speaking with the vocabulary of the Business Domain.
This function currently is so simple that it doesn't bring us any closer.
long line
    return soup.find('span', class_='vGrnd').find('b').text.rstrip() if adjective else soup.find('span', class_='vGrnd').text.rstrip()

Please break that into multiple lines, to improve readability.
Consider defining two functions, one of them having the word "adjective"
in it, so we don't need a conditional at all.
enum
def parse_part_of_speech( ...
    ...
        return 'Существительное'
    ...
        return 'Глагол'
    ...
        return 'Прилагательное'

    return 'error'

It's unclear why most of these are in .title() case
rather than the lower case string we sought.
This code appears to be stringly typed.
Avoid that pattern.
Prefer to define an Enum.
noun vs verb
Function names typically should be verbs.
    ru_translate = ...

Good, I like this identifier, it is informative.
But please use the noun form: ru_translation,
or perhaps abbreviate to ru_word.
keyword args
            word = parse_word(soup, True)
        else:
            word = parse_word(soup)

Certainly that initial call is correct.
But it's a bit obscure.
It doesn't reveal to the reader what is going on.
Prefer to phrase it ... , adjective=True)
Sometimes the author of such a function will choose to
put a * star in the middle of its signature,
so callers are forced to be explicit.

As a small add-on to part of J_H's answer, the following looks like it could be more cleanly done in one-line.

        if part_of_speech == 'Прилагательное':
            word = parse_word(soup, True)
        else:
            word = parse_word(soup)


Since the comparison using == already returns a boolean, and your parse_word function is expecting a boolean, we can simply give that boolean value directly to it.
        word = parse_word(soup, adjective=(part_of_speech == 'Прилагательное'))

This looks rather like another bad habit.
def foo():
    if cond:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Or:
def foo():
    return True if cond else False

As compared to the shorter, simpler, and more direct:
def foo():
    return cond

